# S3 bucket created from AWS management console not accessible with boto

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I have a couple of buckets for an Amazon AWS account. Using boto I can see all the buckets with:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3()
buckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
print buckets
```

However when trying to get a specific bucket:

```
# bucket-1 is present in the conn.get_all_buckets() response
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-1')
```

I can only have access those created e.g. by boto itself. When trying to get a bucket created from within the management console I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated                
does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

When checking the permissions in the management console the buckets all have the same permissions.

Edit: Boto version used was 1.9b

Comment: What version of boto are you using?

Comment: print boto.Version prints 1.9b

Comment: Updating to boto version 2.9.4 solved the issue!

Comment: Wow, 1.9b is quite old.  Glad it's working for you now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to Boto version 2.9.4 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/86

Add tagging to s3 signer so getBucketTagging works …

The generated signature is invalid without this.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/107

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=220402

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket

Comment: What does aws-sdk-js have to do with boto? Am I missing something?